# Java preg_match array

Tags: java, html, regex

Have string `strng = "<title>text1</title><title>text2</title>";`
How to get array like

```
arr[0] = "text1";
arr[1] = "text2";
```

I try to use this, but in result have, and not array `text1</title><title>text2`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<title>(.*)</title>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strng);
matcher.matches();
```

Comment: I think you need to come up with some more examples of exactly what you want. Do you want each array item to extract one sequence of letters followed by a number?

Comment: Hey look, I found markup in there! ...why are you parsing XML with regex?

Comment: Ooh, now it makes sense!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I agree that using an XML / HTML parser [is a better alternative in general](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html), your scenario is simple to solve with regex:

```
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<title>(.*?)</title>").matcher(strng);
while(matcher.find()){
    titles.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Note the non-greedy operator `.*?` and use of `matcher.find()` instead of `matcher.matches()`.

**Reference:**

- [`Pattern` > Reluctant Quantifiers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#reluc)
- [`Matcher.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

Comment: That regex is of course the simplest option, nice! Oh, and wonderful title of your link (parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way)

Comment: @Johan yeah I wish the cthulhu thing was my idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would want a `HTML` / `XML` parser which are built for these kind of jobs.

Although, **if** you have a **small** set of **controlled** information (like the *one* line above) you *might* employ an iteration over [matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).`find()` using a regex such as

```
(?<=\\>)\\w+(?=\\<)
```

Again, anything more complicated than your one liner should be parsed by a proper parser since [regex cannot parse HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Though that would actually give an array of length five, wouldn't it? ( `{ "", "text1", "", "text2", "" }` )

Comment: Yes indeed, I'll revise my answer, and look, it already becomes complicated -> HTML/XML parser *is* the recommended way to go.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like invalid XML since there is no container element, if you make that valid XML you can parse it using an XML parser. For small snippets like the above, I would recommend [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org).

If it is XML or HTML don't use try and use regular expressions, because XML and HTML are not regular languages, and you can't successfully parse either with regular expressions because they can not maintain enough state. Just search stackoverflow for more detailed information why. this comes up constantly and there is lots of information on why not to do it and why it wont' work.