# Java equivalent for PHP preg_grep

Tags: java, php, regex, equivalent

Could somebody tell me if a Java equivalent exist for PHP `preg_grep()`?  Or supply me with a good way to accomplish the same?

I need to do string matching against element in input array and return array with input array's indexes as `preg_grep()` does.

Comment: You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084419/java-preg-match-array

Comment: For future reference, questions about regexes should be tagged [tag:regex] in addition to the language/flavor tags ([tag:java], [tag:php], etc.).  The [tag:qregularexpression] tag refers to a specific implementation, which you are not using.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact equivalent. But you can use the [String#matches(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) function to test if a string matches a given pattern. For example:

```
String s = "stackoverflow";
s.matches("stack.*flow");   // <- true
s.matches("rack.*blow");    // <- false
```

If you want a result array with the matching indices, you can loop over your given input array of strings, check for a match and add the current index of the loop to your result array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this kind of function, using `String.matches()` and iterating over your array :

```
public static List<Integer> preg_grep(String pattern, List<String> array) 
{
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int index = 0;
    for (String item : array) {
        if (item.matches("ba.*")) {
            indexes.add(index);
        }
        ++index;
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

[**Ideone Example**](http://ideone.com/7G9t2S)

Comment: Thanks, I think this should do my job. I am new to java, I have to port my php project to java in order to automate running of script. since I am new to java, i will have to take some time to test your solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
private static String[] filterArrayElem(String[] inputArray) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^a.*)");

    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String inputStr : inputArray) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        if (m.find()) {
            resultList.add(m.group(0));
        }
    }
    return resultList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

You can then use it in the following way:

```
    String [] input = { "apple", "banana", "apricot"};
    String [] result = filterArrayElem(input);
```